# How can I store the output of summary in a variable?

Tags: r

Consider that the following code:

```
baseball <- read.csv("c:\\Users\\Jim\\Downloads\\MLB2008.csv", header = T)
summary(baseball$SALARY)
```

Produces the following output:

```
    Min.  1st Qu.   Median     Mean  3rd Qu.     Max. 
  400000   600000  2200000  4349000  6250000 28000000
```

My Question:

- How can I store the contents of 'Median' (i.e. 2200000) in a variable that I can use later?

For instance, instead of:

```
baseball$Salary_GTE_THAN_MEDIAN <- as.numeric(2200000<=baseball$SALARY)
```

I'd like to write:

```
baseball$Salary_GTE_THAN_MEDIAN <- as.numeric(median_salary<=baseball$SALARY)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

we can subset the `summary` output by the `names` of the output.

```
median_salary <- summary(baseball$SALARY)['Median']
baseball$Salary_GTE_THAN_MEDIAN <- as.numeric(median_salary<=baseball$SALARY)
```

Using a reproducible example

```
data(iris)
Med <- summary(iris$Sepal.Length)['Median']
Med <= iris$Sepal.Length
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the median command. Usage

```
median(x, na.rm = FALSE)
```

https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/median.html

Comment: I actually think this is a good suggestion since it doesn't make the other unwanted calculations, nor does it add names that will need to be dropped in the next step anyway.  Maybe show how they can incorporate it into their code like akrun did.